# Haml without Rails - unescape string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, escaping, haml, html-escape-characters

I'm using Haml outside of Rails and need to print out an unescaped string:

```
%div{ foo: '<?php echo "bar" %>' }
```

becomes

```
<div foo='&lt;?php echo "bar" %&gt;'></div>
```

but I want

```
<div foo='<?php echo "bar" %>'></div>
```

`raw` and `html_safe` are not defined outside of Rails, I tried requiring them and mixing them in, but the end result was the same.
Maybe I'm missing something obvious here...

Comment: you want to print `foo: '<?php echo "bar" %>'` or `'<?php echo "bar" %>'`

Comment: I clarified what I need/expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [`escape_attrs` option](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Options.html#escape_attrs-instance_method) to false.

From the command line you can use something like

```
$ haml --no-escape-attrs my_file.haml
```

or from Ruby something like:

```
Haml::Engine.new(my_template, :escape_attrs => false).to_html
```

Comment: Oh jeez, how did I miss that? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Well to my understanding there is no easy way to do this. Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haml/RScABe1Txh8

Seems you will have to do something *hackish*.

I can only think of writing that specific part in HTML and putting it in `:plain` block.